# How to fix... nginx: [emerg] "root" directive is duplicate in /home/---/web/---/public_html/nginx.conf.sample:32

Tags: nginx

nginx running on ubuntu 20.04, for a (once running) Magento 2.4.5 install

After a reboot of the server, nginx failed to restart.

Running command `sudo nginx -t` brings up error:

`nginx: [emerg] "root" directive is duplicate in /home/--/web/--/public_html/nginx.conf.sample:32 nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`

If I open nginx.conf.sample and comment out line 32, I'm faced with a similar error

`nginx: [emerg] "autoindex" directive is duplicate in /home/--/web/--/public_html/nginx.conf.sample:35 nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`

and so on right down the file, and nginx never passes the test.

Can somebody point me in the right direction please?

Here is the entire nginx.conf.sample file

```
## Example configuration:
# upstream fastcgi_backend {
#    # use tcp connection
#    # server  127.0.0.1:9000;
#    # or socket
#    server   unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
# }
# server {
#    listen 80;
#    server_name mage.dev;
#    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento2;
#    set $MAGE_DEBUG_SHOW_ARGS 0;
#    include /vagrant/magento2/nginx.conf.sample;
# }
#
## Optional override of deployment mode. We recommend you use the
## command 'bin/magento deploy:mode:set' to switch modes instead.
##
## set $MAGE_MODE default; # or production or developer
##
## If you set MAGE_MODE in server config, you must pass the variable into the
## PHP entry point blocks, which are indicated below. You can pass
## it in using:
##
## fastcgi_param  MAGE_MODE $MAGE_MODE;
##
## In production mode, you should uncomment the 'expires' directive in the /static/ location block

# Modules can be loaded only at the very beginning of the Nginx config file, please move the line below to the main config file
# load_module /etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so;

root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;

index index.php;
autoindex off;
charset UTF-8;
error_page 404 403 = /errors/404.php;
#add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge";


# Deny access to sensitive files
location /.user.ini {
    deny all;
}

# PHP entry point for setup application
location ~* ^/setup($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;
    location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;

        fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
        fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=600";
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

# PHP entry point for update application
location ~* ^/update($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;

    location ~ ^/update/index.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Deny everything but index.php
    location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /pub/ {
    location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|custom_options|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
        deny all;
    }
    alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub/;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /static/ {
    # Uncomment the following line in production mode
    # expires max;

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    location ~ ^/static/version\d*/ {
        rewrite ^/static/version\d*/(.*)$ /static/$1 last;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|svgz|webp|avif|avifs|js|css|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|html|json|webmanifest)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
           rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/ {

## The following section allows to offload image resizing from Magento instance to the Nginx.
## Catalog image URL format should be set accordingly.
## See https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/configuration/general/web.html#url-options
#   location ~* ^/media/catalog/.* {
#
#       # Replace placeholders and uncomment the line below to serve product images from public S3
#       # See examples of S3 authentication at https://github.com/anomalizer/ngx_aws_auth
#       # resolver 8.8.8.8;
#       # proxy_pass https://<bucket-name>.<region-name>.amazonaws.com;
#
#       set $width "-";
#       set $height "-";
#       if ($arg_width != '') {
#           set $width $arg_width;
#       }
#       if ($arg_height != '') {
#           set $height $arg_height;
#       }
#       image_filter resize $width $height;
#       image_filter_jpeg_quality 90;
#   }

    try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|svgz|webp|avif|avifs|js|css|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires +1y;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/customer/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/downloadable/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/import/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/custom_options/ {
    deny all;
}

location /errors/ {
    location ~* \.xml$ {
        deny all;
    }
}

# PHP entry point for main application
location ~ ^/(index|get|static|errors/report|errors/404|errors/503|health_check)\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

    fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=18000";
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types
    text/plain
    text/css
    text/js
    text/xml
    text/javascript
    application/javascript
    application/x-javascript
    application/json
    application/xml
    application/xml+rss
    image/svg+xml;
gzip_vary on;

# Banned locations (only reached if the earlier PHP entry point regexes don't match)
location ~* (\.php$|\.phtml$|\.htaccess$|\.htpasswd$|\.git) {
    deny all;
}
```

Thank you for any help you can give me.

[edit]

I have found another configuration file here: `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf'
The contents are:

```
# Server globals
user                    www-data;
worker_processes        auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile    65535;
error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;

include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

# Worker config
events {
        worker_connections  1024;
        use                 epoll;
        multi_accept        on;
}

http {
    # Main settings
    sendfile                        on;
    tcp_nopush                      on;
    tcp_nodelay                     on;
    client_header_timeout           180s;
    client_body_timeout             180s;
    client_header_buffer_size       32k;
    client_body_buffer_size         4m;
    client_max_body_size            256m;
    large_client_header_buffers     4 8k;
    send_timeout                    60s;
    keepalive_timeout               300s;
    keepalive_requests              100000;
    reset_timedout_connection       on;
    server_tokens                   off;
    server_name_in_redirect         off;
    server_names_hash_max_size      512;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size   512;
    charset                         utf-8;

    # FastCGI settings
    fastcgi_buffers                 8 256k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size             256k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size       512k;
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size    32m;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout         300s;
    fastcgi_read_timeout            300s;
    fastcgi_send_timeout            180s;
    fastcgi_cache_lock              on;
    fastcgi_cache_lock_timeout      60s;
    fastcgi_cache_background_update on;
    fastcgi_cache_revalidate        on;
    
    # Proxy settings
    proxy_redirect                  off;
    proxy_set_header                Host $host;
    proxy_set_header                X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header                X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass_header               Set-Cookie;
    proxy_buffers                   32 4k;
    proxy_connect_timeout           300s;
    proxy_read_timeout              300s;
    proxy_send_timeout              180s;

    # Log format
    log_format  main    '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $request '
                        '"$status" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    log_format  bytes   '$body_bytes_sent';
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;

    # Mime settings
    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Compression
    gzip                on;
    gzip_static         on;
    gzip_vary           on;
    gzip_comp_level     6;
    gzip_min_length     1024;
    gzip_buffers        16 8k;
    gzip_http_version   1.1;
    gzip_types          text/plain text/css text/javascript text/js text/xml application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml application/xml+rss application/x-font-ttf image/svg+xml font/opentype;
    gzip_proxied        any;
    gzip_disable        "MSIE [1-6]\.";

    # Cloudflare https://www.cloudflare.com/ips
    set_real_ip_from 103.21.244.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from 103.22.200.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from 103.31.4.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from 104.16.0.0/13;
    set_real_ip_from 104.24.0.0/14;
    set_real_ip_from 108.162.192.0/18;
    set_real_ip_from 131.0.72.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from 141.101.64.0/18;
    set_real_ip_from 162.158.0.0/15;
    set_real_ip_from 172.64.0.0/13;
    set_real_ip_from 173.245.48.0/20;
    set_real_ip_from 188.114.96.0/20;
    set_real_ip_from 190.93.240.0/20;
    set_real_ip_from 197.234.240.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from 198.41.128.0/17;
    # set_real_ip_from 2400:cb00::/32;
    # set_real_ip_from 2606:4700::/32;
    # set_real_ip_from 2803:f800::/32;
    # set_real_ip_from 2405:b500::/32;
    # set_real_ip_from 2405:8100::/32;
    # set_real_ip_from 2a06:98c0::/29;
    # set_real_ip_from 2c0f:f248::/32;
    real_ip_header     CF-Connecting-IP;

    # SSL PCI compliance
    ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:20m;
    ssl_session_timeout 60m;
    ssl_buffer_size     1400;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers         "ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS";
    ssl_dhparam         /etc/ssl/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ecdh_curve      secp384r1;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    resolver 213.186.33.99  valid=300s ipv6=off;
    resolver_timeout    60s;

    # Error pages
    error_page 403 /error/404.html;
    error_page 404 /error/404.html;
    error_page 410 /error/410.html;
    error_page 500 501 502 503 504 505 /error/50x.html;

    # Proxy cache
    proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=2 keys_zone=cache:10m inactive=60m max_size=1024m;
    proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
    proxy_temp_path  /var/cache/nginx/temp;
    proxy_ignore_headers Expires Cache-Control;
    proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_502;
    proxy_cache_valid any 1d;

    # FastCGI cache
    fastcgi_cache_path /var/cache/nginx/micro levels=1:2 keys_zone=microcache:10m max_size=1024m inactive=30m;
    fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
    fastcgi_cache_methods GET HEAD;
    fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_503;
    fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
    add_header X-FastCGI-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

    # Cache bypass
    map $http_cookie $no_cache {
        default 0;
        ~SESS 1;
        ~wordpress_logged_in 1;
    }

    # File cache (static assets)
    open_file_cache          max=100000 inactive=180s;
    open_file_cache_valid    120s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors   off;

    # Wildcard include
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/domains/*.conf;
}
```

In case that helps you help me :)

Comment: comment root on Lin 32 out as stated, as long as it's not in a server or location it should not be there

Comment: Nginx tells you, what is the issue, fix one by one. however, it loos for me that due `/home/xadmin` there is a admin panel involed, is that true?

Comment: that's correct. it's Hestia

Comment: I then get: nginx: [emerg] "autoindex" directive is duplicate in /home/--/web/--/public_html/nginx.conf.sample:35 nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed Commenting out all "directive is duplicate" lines leads to: nginx: [emerg] no port in upstream "fastcgi_backend" in /home/xadmin/web/---/public_html/nginx.conf.sample:51 nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed


(deleted this comment and reposting as I'd left some of the path intact and suddenly had an influx of Russian IPs appearing in my firewall logs)

Comment: The `nginx.conf.sample` file posted above is the default that was installed along with the Magento upgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appear to have fixed this by deleting the contents of nginx.conf.sample and uploading as a blank file.

I don't know why this works, or if this will cause issues in the future, but nginx started, which was my main issue.

Comment: This can only be true if somewhere down the line of /etc/nginx/nginx.conf the sample file is referenced to be included. I cannot speak for all Linux distributions - but this is very unlikely to be a standard behaviour.